# Asynchronous WCF on server, some calls get lost

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

My WCF looks like this:

```
public interface IIO
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Method1(string Data, Identity ID);

    [OperationContract]
    string Method2(string Data, Identity ID);
    .
    .
    .
    [OperationContract]
    Task<int> Async1(string Data, Identity ID);

    [OperationContract]
    Task<int> Async2(string Data, Identity ID);

}
```

This is the implementation of Async1 on server:

```
    public async Task<int> Async1(string Data, Identity ID)
    {
        var myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => InternalAsync1(Data, ID));
        var result = await myTask;
        return result;
    }
```

Client side works like this: I have the proxy instance, once created to be used for life time of client, then use methods one after the other. At he beginning I thought keeping the proxy instance for a few seconds will save some time for re-connection, or I may be wrong...

```
GlobalInstance_of_ServiceReference.Async1(data, ID);
//No waiting for operation to finish, it may take a long time...
Environmen.Exit(0);
//Appdomain will get destroyed by mother application after this
```

After executing any of the Async tasks, clients gets unloaded from appdomain. Client does not wait for async operation to be finished, it may be a long running task on server.

Async methods are in fact returning void, or here returning a dummy 0 for complying with format of Task<>.

Why do I need them to be async on server side? Because I simply want the request to continue on server after client is destroyed. Other scenario (client side async) would finish on server after client unloaded, or I had made a mistake...

What is the problem now?
Some of the async requests (exactly last instruction on client before client unload, after some other sync requests to the same server) easily don't get executed without any warning.

Any advice about my architecture or techniques is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

1- Environment.Exit(0) was terminating the running appdomain and the whole process. I changed configuration of this part. This is important to know: Environment.Exit does not only terminate current appdomain. It terminates the whole application. The point is that WCF was being internally called from the same web site, so, this termination in whole application was fatal for continuation of running.

2- I changed my operation contracts to "IsOneWay=true". This is easier in implementation than "async Task" template. There are resources on the net pointing out that One way operations may block the client until they can insert their request on que of server. This was already what I wanted. I didn't want the process to proceed without successfully finishing this task. So it was not a problem for me.